# MacBook dropping Wi-Fi connection

Tags: macos, wifi, hardware

I have 2 MacBook Pros: a Late 2008 model and a Late 2011 model. Both of them are running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

The Late 2008 model has no issues connecting to Wi-Fi networks.

The Late 2011 model has a terrible Wi-Fi reception (typical **MCS** in the range of 0 to 5). It remains even after replacing the Wi-Fi card with a different used one, and even a new flat Wi-Fi card. I even tried deleting and adding the Airport again in the Network panel.

The antenna wires look fine. What else could be causing such poor reception?

Please see the attached screenshots:

[image]

[image: system config screen]

Comment: Any change in MCS when you disable bluetooth or chance you can put an external USB WiFi on to be sure it's not software on the Mac? I'm hoping it's anything but that Mac itself.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...was any work done to the LCD of the 2011 MBP?  The wires may "look fine" from where they connect to the logic board, but it doesn't rule out their condition where you can't see them.